# How to bake extra turkey legs along with a whole turkey?

Tags: baking, turkey

I have bought 4 Turkey turkey legs that I would like to serve at the same time as the rest of the turkey.  I am baking the turkey.   At what point in time during the baking do I add the additional legs so they are done at the same time?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the size of your turkey, how you intend to cook it, your oven temperature.....it is best to use a thermometer.  Are the other legs still attached to the turkey?  If so, why wouldn't they all go in together?  If not (which is how I would do it), I would start with the legs, and add the breast later (which cooks to a lower temperature).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly, it depends on the size of the turkey and the size of the extra legs, and whether the turkey is stuffed or not. I always cut the legs off my turkey so they don't dry out, they take between 1 and 1.5 hours to cook. I usually let the turkey bake for an hour before adding the legs, then I start checking the legs' temperature an hour after that. This generally means the legs and turkey body are done about the same time. I'm usually roasting a 16lb (7kg) turkey though, if yours is smaller you'd probably want to reduce those times somewhat.

Comment: do you bake the legs covered or uncovered?

Comment: It doesn't matter much with legs @Bookaholic.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.  If you let your breast roast, then add the legs, it seems to me you will have overcooked white meat, and/or under cooked dark meat.  It is going to take a lot longer for the legs to "dry out" than the breast.

Comment: Legs are much smaller than breasts, have a greater surface area and have a large bone running through the center of the meat so they cook much faster @moscafj.

Comment: While I agree with your description of a turkey leg, I can't vouch for your cooking process.  It just hasn't worked that way for me.